# Stop XML file form Overwriting the data using powershell

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I am able to save VM name and its status(deallocated/running) in XML file using Octopus deploy tool.
But in couple of instances the data gets overwrite.
Allow me to give you a Preface -
Octopus runs the powershell for (not on the servers) all servers at the same time, thus the data is getting stored in the XML file at the same time for all the servers.
I want to implement a wait operation, so the data store operation should wait until the initial data is written in the file and saved successfully. I have tried File IO class but no luck.

Here is the current code -

```
$VM = "#{VMname}"
$Status = ($VMStats | Where Code -Like 'PowerState/*')[0].DisplayStatus
$CurrentEnv = "#{Octopus.Environment.Name}"
$fileName = "F:\folder1\$($CurrentEnv)_ServerFile.xml"
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);

$newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.Root.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement($VM));
$newXmlEmployee.SetAttribute("Status",$Status);

$xmlDoc.Save($fileName);
```

Comment: Do you have some more code that's executing the code in your example? How is that code triggering this code(jobs, processes, etc.) ? Is it correct to assume that ```$fileName``` represents a file that is shared by each of the processes?

Comment: @derekbaker783 - this is the code which saves the data in XML file, we have to make changes in this code snippet. Yes $FileName is the file where status of all VM are getting write.

Answer (score 0):

How is the step running the script configured?

It might be possible to do this with a worker if your VMs are registered as targets. You could have the script run on a worker on behalf of each VM target and use a rolling deployment window size of 1.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ryan, I have to use downgraded version of ocotous in which worker attributes are not present. Ocotous version - 3.17.14

Comment: In that case, you should have an Option for "Run on the Octopus Server on behalf of each deployment target", but that would require the script running on the Octopus Server to access this information in some way.